# DataGridView CellSelect and FullRowSelect

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I have several datagridviews that we had set to `FullRowSelect`.  The users are now requesting the ability to select on single cells for copy functions.

I set the `DataGridView` to `CellSelect` but when I run the app, when I click on the Row Header it doesn't highlight the Full Row, only the first column.

I tried using the `RowHeaderMouseClick` with a `CellMouseClick` to get the selection mode to shift but in order for `RowHeaderMouseClick` to select it fully I am having to click on the row header multiple times.

```
private void DataGridView_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}
```

How can I easily or not so easily switch back and forth between `CellSelect` and `FullRowSelect` depending on what they have selected on the grid?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand you, you want to be able to select single cells but also easily select a full row?

If that's the case, set SelectionMode to `RowHeaderSelect`.

Answer (score 3):

add this one line code.

```
this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = isTrue == true ? DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect : DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

1- You are actually using the DataGridView Structure, and not your object DataGridView.

2- The SelectionMode shouldn't be modified every time the user click a Row, but in your Constructor of your program.

Example

```
public MyForm()
{
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}
```

Comment: I am using the object, it is just called DataGridView in the example. I will change the name for clarity.  As far as the selection mode it will change based on what the user wants.  They might click on a cell so it should be CellSelect.  If they click the RowHeader it would be FullRowSelect.